# Sending input to Java app(Minecraft) from C#

Tags: c#, java

I'm trying to make a program that sends some text to the Minecraft game, which is a java application - but I'm writing the code in C#

this is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Minecraft1
{
public partial class Form1
{ 
    [DllImportAttribute( "User32.dll" )]

    private static extern int FindWindow( String ClassName, String
    WindowName );

    [DllImportAttribute( "User32.dll" )]
    private static extern int SetForegroundWindow( int hWnd );

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //to activate an application
        int hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Minecraft");
        if (hWnd > 0)
        {
            SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
            SendKeys.Send("/Give metrius 64 64");
        }
    }
}
}
```

but when I run it, and click the button it activates the window and sends something like this
"meeeetrrrius"

Any clue on this?

Comment: well it should send "/Give metrius 64 64" - but it sends nothing the first time i click the button

Comment: Is that text exactly what is sent?  Have you tried opening a notepad window and sending the text to it.  This will confirm what text appears.

Comment: if i send the text to notepad it sends it correcrtly..

Comment: No offense Mathias, but `/Give metrius 64 64` won't work, because `64` isn't an item - Do `/Give metrius diamond_sword 64 0`

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that the window is not in the foreground before the keys are sent
Can you try:

```
    if (hWnd > 0)
    {
        SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
        Thread.Sleep(50); // intentional delay to ensure the window is in the foreground
        SendKeys.Send("/Give metrius 64 64");
    }
```

Comment: okay ive just tested it - now it wrote "/giiiiiiiiiiiiiiivve metrius 64 64"

Comment: hmm it must be something with the minecraft program - ive just tryed to send it to the minecraft server, and that works - hmm..

Comment: try increasing the sleep.  If that fails then you could try sending each letter one at a time with a sleep in between each, however its most likely something to do with the input reading of the java program

Comment: hm ye ive tryed to send each letter.. but if i click the button first time it wont send anything - i'll try look at it

Comment: if it is working correctly now can you please post what you did to make it work correctly.  Then if someone else has a similar problem they will be able to see your solution.

Comment: Write : 
Sendkeys.sendWait("/Give");
thread.sleep(10);
Sendkeys.sendWait("Metrius");
thread.sleep(10);

and so on :D